# ODP.NET (Oracle Data Provider) schema

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, tablespace

I have a question about OPD.NET in combination with Oracle tablespaces.

We have a webapplication that runs smoothly in a production environment using ODP.NET as dataprovider for Entity Framework. De model was created from the database (which pre-existed), and the tables in the edmx file look like this:

```
<EntitySet Name="ES_T_ALG_INFO" EntityType="Model.Store.ES_T_ALG_INFO" store:Type="Tables" Schema="ES_ANON" />
```

As you can see the designer added the Schema attribute, which corresponds with the ES_ANON tablespace.

The client now wants to re-use the application for a different unit, which has a different tablespace. If I search-replace the ES_ANON with the new schema, there is no problem. If I don't do this (or remove the attributes all together), the ObjectDataContext can't find my tables..

Is there a way to programmatically set the tablespace ?

If any more ifnormation is required, don't hesitate to let me know. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
<EntitySet Name="ES_T_ALG_INFO" EntityType="Model.Store.ES_T_ALG_INFO" store:Type="Tables" Schema="" />
```

The schema attriute is required (which I did not know). When you leave it empty, the ODPnet provider will use the default schema, which in Oracle is the same as the username.

You can access different schema's through some hacks I found, but since I don't really need that I'm not investigating further.